# Is X-Men First Class based earlier in time than X-Men Origins:Wolverine?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, chronology, comic-adaptation, x-men-first-class

If X-Men First Class (XFC) is based before X-Men Origins (XMO) then how did [Emma Frost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Frost) end up being captured by [Colonel Stryker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Stryker)?

The last we see of Emma Frost in XFC she is with Magneto and Raven, but it doesn't make sense that Magneto would let her be captured and not do anything about it especially when she is captured by someone who treats mutants so badly.

Also we see that Professor Xavier is walking at the end of XMO which would mean that XMO is before XFC. At the end of XMO he invites the captured mutants to join his school but in XFC he didn't create the school until he was in a wheelchair.

Are the films meant to be in chronological order or should they just be seen as two completely separate movies?

Comment: For some reason I had the thought that Xavier wasn't actually there, but was projecting an image of himself to save the kids, but I'm not sure about that because I haven't seen the movie in a bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your main question, X-Men First Class is based before X-Men Origins.

X-Men First Class is [based in the 60s](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270798/).

> In 1962, the United States government enlists the help of Mutants with
>   superhuman abilities to stop a malicious dictator who is determined to
>   start world war III.

In Origins, Striker doesn't [approach Wolverine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins%3a_Wolverine#Plot) until the 70s.

> In 1973, Victor (Liev Schrieber) attempts to rape a local village
>   woman, but is stopped after killing a senior officer. James (Hugh
>   Jackman) defends his brother, and the two are sentenced to execution
>   by firing squad, which they survive. Major William Stryker (Danny
>   Huston) approaches them, now in military custody, and offers them
>   membership in Team X

In regards to Xavier walking, there is a lot of debate as to which movie is canon and there is currently no correct answer (AFAIK). First class also seems to have a lot of other [continuity problems](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110604121634AA6LouL).

Comment: This might give some idea.http://screenrant.com/bryan-singer-x-men-first-class-story-characters-sequels-rob-111673/all/1/

Comment: As far as i see it, First class is the prequel to the trilogy and wolverine can be taken as a stand alone movie. First class has the earliest timeline.

Comment: Actually the best way to view the 5 movies from what I've seen is to view the Trilogy as one group, Origins as a stand-alone until Wolverine comes out, and First class until its sequel comes out.  I have heard rumors of trying to tying the films together but continuity problems abound that may just be swept under a rug.

Comment: @TylerShads hahaha thanks, yeah I realise the controversy about posting a YA link, but it was quite an amazing one to find on there—it has spelling, detail and all that good answer jazz.

Comment: In addition, Charles Xavier mentions to one of the head agents "Agent *Stryker*" of the CIA, that he was thinking about his son "William". While ambiguous of his age, would be safe to presume his son William Stryker was only a boy at the time of *First Class*.

Answer (score 4):

From the [X Men: First Class article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_First_Class):

> Goldman added the film was kind of an "alternate history" for the X-Men, saying that while rebooting the writers did not want to go fully "against the canon of the X-Men trilogy", comparing to the various approaches the comic had in over fifty years of publication.

This lines from wiki says that they want to start fresh, not fully dependent on original story arc that's why they didn't take care of inconsistency with original.

From IAR EXCLUSIVE INTERVIEW [(Source)](http://www.iamrogue.com/news/interviews/item/4757-iar-exclusive-interview-producer-lauren-shuler-donner-talks-%E2%80%98x-men-first-class%E2%80%99-cameos-a-possible-sequel-emma-frost-%E2%80%98the-wolverine%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98deadpool%E2%80%99.html):

> Q: Is January Jones’ Emma Frost somehow the same character we saw in
> X-Men Origins: Wolverine?
> Donner: No, she’s Emma from First Class. That’s who she was and she’s
> the real Emma Frost. I think January did a pretty good job of
> portraying her.
>
> Q: So there is no connection between the First Class Emma Frost and the
> one we see in X-Men Origins: Wolverine?
> Donner: No … not really, no.