# How does Professor X actually get paralysed?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, comic-adaptation

Recently I have watched a variety of X-Men movies, including X-Men Origins: Wolverine and X-Men First Class. In X-Men First Class the story at the end of the movie indicates that Charles Xavier loses his ability to walk after a shot fired at Magneto hits him in his lower back.

However, at the end of X-Men Origins: Wolverine Charles Xavier is seen walking towards those who escaped.

Obviously, in both instances this is probably just artistic license changing the story. According to X-Men canon, how does Professor Xavier actually get paralysed?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/2608/1405 The last line explains that First Class has a lot of continuity errors.

Comment: And in x-men the last stand, Prof. X is walking at the beginning, even though his age in the scene would suggest he should already be paralyzed.

Comment: The X-men movies in particular are notorious for terrible continuity. http://io9.com/5966264/8-ways-x-men-movie-continuity-is-irretrievably-fucked Hopefully they'll somehow manage an actual explanation in Days of Future Past.

Comment: While he was in the Himalayas, Lucifer drops a stone on his legs and it cripples him, but a lady named sage hears him through telepathy and rescues him

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really that on-topic for this site in the first place, seeing how you are just asking about comic continuity completely independent of any (apparently contradicting) depictions in the movies, which you only use as an inspiration for the question rather than their subject. You might want to point out the connection and relevance of the question to the movies a little more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**X-Men (1st series) # 20**](http://www.uncannyxmen.net/db/issues/showquestion.asp?fldAuto=809): *(May 1966)*

> [image: X-Men]
>
> Years ago, [Xavier](http://marvel.com/universe/Professor_X) discovered a city in Tibet being under some sort of alien mind-control.
>
> The professor managed to inspire a rebellion against [Lucifer](http://marvel.com/universe/Lucifer_%28Quist%29), and the alien was forced to abandon his base, however not before **causing a block of concrete to fall and crush Xavier’s legs**.

Comment: Some good info Oliver...another prime example of how the Hollywood folks tend to screw up the real story started from comics...although they are sometimes well done, they aren't correct.

Comment: It got more screwed up now :/